# Debian showing red green blue screen

Tags: debian, dual-boot

I dual booted Debian 10.0.0 [XFCE] with windows 10 and right after installing Debian I selected Debian on the grub menu.

After which I see a red then green then blue color screen in a loop.

It is the same problem if I select rescue mode

This is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToUiL.jpg

My PC is HP ProOne 400 G2 non-touch all-in-one.

My PC hardware: [Hardware.htm](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16Q2x6I9OWrwiivxcNlvluq8wGqZOp8kR) or [Hardware.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e5gssfVu3jmYbQRcEYzM-xUiXJmyZguJ)

Hitting the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key after booting to get it to show anything, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> after a minute or two to get to a text mode login does not work.

I don't know what other information I should provide. Ask me if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your video hardware isn't being detected properly. Try to edit your grub command line and see if you can add `nomodeset` or edit/add `gfxpayload=1024x768` to try booting with a different video mode.

You can get into grub 'edit mode' by hitting the <kbd>E</kbd> key on the grub menu item. This brings up a rudimentary editor where you can move around with the arrow keys and replace text in the grub command line.  Some ubuntu docs [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/key-to-show-grub-menu-ubuntu) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting) but should still work:

Note the part about <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot with the modified command line.

Comment: Third line from the bottom starting with `linux`.. arrow down to it and then arrow to the right. remove the word `quiet` and replace it with `nomodeset` (removing `quiet` just prints the boot log to the screen - useful for debugging) Then hit CTRL+X to boot with those settings. NOTE:  Sometimes I'll add `vga=791` as well to force a generic VESA video mode. It depends on how finicky the hardware is.  In the past, I've also had to add other boot arguments like `pci=probeonly` and `noapic` and `nolapic` to get things booting.

Comment: Looks like you might need to add `pci=nomsi` or `pci=noaer` as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected

Comment: `link not ready` just means your wifi card isn't active. The green OKs are the kernel performing various startup processes. Normally you don't see those since most distributions put a VGA splash screen up over it. It looks like you might have a login prompt on a different virtual terminal. Try CTRL+ALT+F2 or F3 or F4 and see if you get a `login:`.  If you can, try and login. You might be able to glean more info from the logs. Perhaps follow some of those links above. It looks like this is possibly an active bug with specific hardware and has some workarounds available.

Comment: As I understand it,  Grub tried starting what it thought was a compatible video mode on the given hardware. It didn't work. The link above shows some sort of bug which looks very  similar to your error messages. you can try running `startx`, which is the customary way of starting an X session from a command prompt, but it's quite likely you will just get the red, green and blue screen again as the kernel tries using the same video mode it told Grub to. You'll have to dig into configuring X11 for your specific hardware and X stack (wayland, xorg, etc). I don't know how it's done these days.

Comment: Sorry it needs try-harder mode :/ It looks like you have an Intel HD 530 video chipset. You'll have to google around and see how to get it up and running or what the exact fix is. You could try another distro which sometimes helps. maybe start here?  https://www.google.com/search?q=startx+intel+hd+graphics+530

Comment: First of all, could you type in `lspci -nn` after your login in CLI?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the same PC.

As far as I understand the resolution for the screen is 1600x900 which is not a normal mode for Linux, I tried to add vga=868 ( 1440x900x32 ) but it didn't work. Did anybody have a solution for this?